# Require fields from a directive field type

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

Reference this example: http://jsbin.com/cenugiziju/edit?html,js,output

I have created a directive: `example-directive`
This directive is made up of a templateUrl which has a label and an input within this html file.  This field is marked as `required` within `vm.formFields`.

If you take a peek down within the Form section, you will notice that `$valid` is already set to `true` even though the required directive is not populated.  I would have expected this to be `false`.

Is there a way to make Formly require fields that are brought in from a custom directive which has fields on it?

Comment: when you set the required field that does not state whether or not the item is required... you need to tell it when is required... like require:'^ngModel' or require:'^form', this allowes you to use it in the link function in the directive... https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive, you need to set the field as required... p.s your example is kinda messy... where is the formaly-form directive?

Comment: I'll take a look at your link stuff.  Thanks man.  The formly-form directive is from the formly.js script that is included within the html field.

Comment: @Jony-Y Does this `require:'^ngModel'` go within the directive itself?  Should the thing that it require be the controller on the main page?  or the form on the main page (`vm.formName` in this case)?   Does `link` setup how the two items communicate with each other?

Comment: yes, the require:'^ngModel' goes in the directive.js and forces you to use ngModel in the directive and then control it in the link function .no, the thing that should be required is the input field where ever it is... just add to it required... dont mix require and required... require means that the directive must have that attribute in it... required means that the field in is required

Comment: Would have time to update the example provided?  I have been banging my head against the wall today trying to get your idea to take off but I am not having any luck.  The way that you word it...it seems extremely simple but I can't envision how the require/required/link all tie in together to make it form realize that the fields within the directive are required.

Comment: I think that I might have confused you a bit...can you tell me what is it that you want to accomplish? do you have to use formalyJS?(there is no need to) Ill help you solve this

Comment: Yes, I need to use formlyJS.  We are switching our forms to use formly.  I understand that it is not required but we want to use Formly so all of our forms can use the same field types/etc with little rework as possible.  I am trying to accomplish two things...one, add field(s) to a form where one of the items in the form is a directive (the link in the question above shows this working).  Two, I need the fields that I am pulling in from the directive to honor their requried/minValue/maxValue/etc settings (this is the part where I am struggling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok
sorry about the mixup and delay.
I have created the answer you were looking for.
because you are entering a directive you actually need to send the options to that directive with the values you need... 
this is the working example... this means though you will need to handle all the validations and so on yourself since you are not generating the element via FormalyJS but in your own directive.(make sure there is no other way to do it...)

this is the corrected code with required/ maxlength /minlength:

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/bobahahawa/1/edit?html,js,output)

what I actually did was pass the options for the Formly to my directive and add the validations to it

```
   app.directive('exampleDirective', function() {
return {
  templateUrl: 'example-directive.html',
  scope:{
    options:'=options',
    ngModel:'=ngModel'
  },
  link:function(scope, element, attrs){
    scope.isRequired = scope.options.templateOptions.required;
    scope.minValue = scope.options.templateOptions.min;
    scope.maxValue = scope.options.templateOptions.max;
  }
};
```

});

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="example-directive.html">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{::id}}">{{options.templateOptions.label}}</label>
    <input id="{{::id}}" name="{{::id}}" class="form-control" ng-model="ngModel" ng-required="isRequired" ng-minLength="{{minValue}} ng-maxLength={{maxValue}}"/>
  </div>
</script>
```

this is the addition to the template in the vm.formFields
 template: ''

so now when you want to add a field you will need to pass the data to the directive and in the directive add the corresponding code...
I am not hugely familiar with Formly, but this is the solution that I can give you

NOTE:
I pass the option item to the directive because this is how FormalyJS constructs it.... you can always use your own... but since it renders after the formly directive, figured it would be easier

**EDIT**

here is an updated [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/qahewimame/edit?html,js,output)

you can see that I had to add to the directive the ngModel... you can also do it by require and then use it, I prefer to do it like this... but you have to pass it to the div defining the directive... 
checkout the updated code

Comment: Thanks for this answer man!  I can see that it is def working on jsbin but when I go to apply this logic to my project I am getting an error that `options` is undefined when it goes to run the code within the `link` function (`scope.options.template....`).  I added the `options` attribute to the div.  I would have assumed that adding the `options` there is what actually sends all of the stuff associated with the options to the directive.  Am I misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: do you want to give me an example and Ill help you solve it? you need to define options in the directive telling it to bind the options from formlyjs to your isolated directive scope. the options data is what formlyjs returns after it compiles the fields (or vm.formFields in our case), you can always just use your own and pass them... so we are adding a new scope variable to the directive called options and bind it with the data you've sent to formlyjs... but to help out more I need to see where things crash

Comment: I'm still looking into the issue (I'll try to figure it out before I ask for help as I learn better that way).  However, looking at the jsbin that you provided...do I need to return the validation from the directive back up to the main form?  It loads with the form being `$invalid` (which is great) but if you enter data into the field the form still believes that it is `$invalid`.  I would assume that I need to bubble up the validation or something up to the form so it can update the `$valid/$invalid/etc` fields accordingly.

Comment: in the jsbin if you add values the form changes...go to my jsbin and enter bla bla and you'll see its valid... anyhow you can always maintain it by yourself but you shouldn't, just looked at my code and it works to me

Comment: I'm an idiot...I forgot there was a minLength on it :)  I do notice, that the value being entered doesn't get added to the `vm.model` array like normal fields that do not use directives do.  For example, if you added the following to the `formFields` array you can see how the new input gets added to the model: `{key: 'exampleDirective',type: 'input',templateOptions: {label: 'Input example'}}`

Comment: if you want to add the ngModel to the input then just assign it... in the formly they set to the ngModel the key value... so in your code in the html you can do the same... like ng-model="options.key" or you can pass it to the directive via the div and then bind it in the scope like scope:{ngmodel:'=ngModel'}... I told you, that going with the directive you have to do everything yourself... Formly js will not create the fields for you... as far as I know

Comment: Can I make my directive require `^ngModel` to achieve similar results?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89713/discussion-between-jony-y-and-holt).

Comment: I'm not sure if you get alerted that I posted in the chat or not...but I sent you something in the chat :-)